# highslide - iframe - how to open a page that is redirected?

Tags: iframe, highslide

I havn't found yet any topic that correspond to my question.
With highslide, I open external pages with iframes.

```
<a href="http://sitename" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.htmlExpand(this, {  
objectType: 'iframe', width: 900,  height: 600 } )"> the link </a>
```

That code works very well.

The trouble is, I have one special url.
When I open sitename1.com, the page is redirected to sitename2.com
And even when I open sitename2.com, the page reloads sitename2.com

So the iframe doesn't work anymore, the link opens normally, leaving my website. I have tried hs.preserveContent, but it didn't work.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Could you send us live demo ?

Comment: I wish I could. I'm working on an intranet, with an intern webmail for a city. As soon as I can show you an exemple, I share it.